# K-Means Clustering Problem in large 3D image CAD datasets

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I have 1 million unclassified cad images in one folder and I need to cluster those images according to its similarity in 350 cluster folders, i.e k=350.
Out of 350 folders after clustering,

1. There are around 120 folders that contain mixed images( similar and totally different images).
   My problem is why there are mixed folders in my clustered data folders?
2. There are different folders that contain similar images. Why similar images are not clustered into the same folder? For eg. cluster folder 2 and cluster folder 30 contains similar images.[image]

What might be the logic behind such a result?
Is K means not suitable for large image datasets?

I have attached the images for mixed data for a clear understanding.

Thanking in advance.

[image]

Comment: When you say folder, do you mean a cluster? Not like a directory on a file system, right?

Comment: What kind of features did you use for clustering, raw image pixels or something else?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
Yes, I mean clustered result folder.
I used VGG-16 to extract the features from images.

Comment: I have used raw images pixels.

Comment: You must mention all the steps you did to get your features. Size of the vector from VGG16. Did you do any dimensionality reduction, any normalization/standardization/whitening of the features?

Comment: How did you chose k to be 350?

Comment: 1. Since the data were very huge, I didn`t get the perfect Elbow point so I decided to take K=350 based on SSE Value. I have attached the image above for K value.
2. Size of the vector from VGG-16 is (224,224).
3. I haven't used any dimensionality reduction functionality like PCA..
4. All the images are generated using CAD software from the isometric view with its default lighting and default. So all images have the same lighting and shading effect.

Comment: VGG16 vector should not be 224,224,3 - that is the input feature size (pixel space). The output vector should be something like 2048. So fix that. And try to do PCA as well, hopefully you can compress this into 100 or maybe even 10

Comment: Based on that elbow plot I'd suggest trying something like 50 or 100 clusters.

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake. The size of the image that I have used is (244,244) and the feature vector size is 4096.
And Thank you so much for your help.I will try clustering in different K values and see the result. :)